# calculate inv(A) * B by eigen3

Tags: eigen3

I want to solve the following matrix equation by using eigen3 library

```
A * x = B
```

where both `A` and `B` are N-by-N matrices.
The solution is obviously that `x = inv(A) * B`.
From the eigen3 [website](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html#title4), it is not recommended to explicitly compute the inverse of a matrix, instead, one solve the linear system directly is perferable. However, the document only gives one [example](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) to solve

```
A * x = b
```

where `b` is a column vector.

How can I generalize the example to calculate `x = inv(A) * B`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `x` meant to be a matrix? If it is an NxN matrix, you can apply the example to every column-vector of `B` and `x`. Note that you only need to do the decomposition once, then call its `solve` method repeatedly

Comment: How large is `N`? For `N<=4` you can also compute the inverse explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial doesn't mention it but the [API documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SolverBase.html#a7fd647d110487799205df6f99547879d) does: B can be a matrix.

Their example:

```cpp
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(3,3);
MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Random(3,2);
cout << "Here is the invertible matrix A:" << endl << A << endl;
cout << "Here is the matrix B:" << endl << B << endl;
MatrixXd X = A.lu().solve(B);
cout << "Here is the (unique) solution X to the equation AX=B:" << endl << X << endl;
cout << "Relative error: " << (A*X-B).norm() / B.norm() << endl;
```